# How to attach files to ruby hipchat messages?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, hipchat

I want to send text files through hipchat using the [ruby hipchat-rb gem](https://github.com/hipchat/hipchat-rb).  There doesn't seem to be a way to do this described in the readme of this gem.  Is it possible to do this?

Comment: https://github.com/hipchat/hipchat-rb/blob/e65b02d966ebce30d0601a3235fa6e6e9cef3216/lib/hipchat/user.rb#L43

Comment: got it that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the working solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'hipchat'

client = HipChat::Client.new('HIPCHAT_TOKEN', :api_version => 'v2', :server_url => 'HIPCHAT_URL')
client.user('some_username').send_file('message', File.open('some-file.txt') )
```