# Ruby hipchat gem invalid send file

Tags: ruby, rubygems, hipchat

So this is related to an earlier post I made on this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41271497/how-to-attach-files-to-ruby-hipchat-messages).  This is essentially what I am using to send files via hipchat:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'hipchat'

client = HipChat::Client.new('HIPCHAT_TOKEN', :api_version => 'v2', :server_url => 'HIPCHAT_URL')
client.user('some_username').send_file('message', File.open('./output/some-file.csv') )
client['some_hipchat_room'].send_file('some_user', 'message', File.open('./output/some-file.csv') )
```

Now for some reason the send_file method is invalid:

```
/path/to/gems/hipchat-1.5.4/lib/hipchat/errors.rb:40:in `response_code_to_exception_for': You requested an invalid method. path:https://hipchat.illum.io/v2/user/myuser@myemail/share/file?auth_token=asdfgibberishasdf method:Net::HTTP::Get (HipChat::MethodNotAllowed)
    from /path/to/gems/gems/hipchat-1.5.4/lib/hipchat/user.rb:50:in `send_file'
```

Comment: I think this indicating that you should be using POST instead of GET, but I'm not sure because I haven't used this library nor Hipchat.

Comment: What version of the gem are you using? `cat Gemfile.lock | grep hipchat`

Comment: `hipchat (1.5.4)`

Comment: https://github.com/hipchat/hipchat-rb/blob/v1.5.4/lib/hipchat/user.rb#L44

Comment: I edited my post to help with debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I think this indicating that you should be using POST instead of GET, but I'm not sure because I haven't used this library nor Hipchat.

Looking at the [question you referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41271497/how-to-attach-files-to-ruby-hipchat-messages) and [the source posted by another user](https://github.com/hipchat/hipchat-rb/blob/e65b02d966ebce30d0601a3235fa6e6e9cef3216/lib/hipchat/user.rb#L43) they're sending the request using `self.class.post`, and your debug output shows `Net::HTTP::Get`

To debug, could you try,

```
file = Tempfile.new('foo').tap do |f|
  f.write("the content")
  f.rewind
end

user = client.user(some_username)
user.send_file('some bytes', file)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that I was attempting to connect to the server via `http` instead of `https`.  If the following client is causing issues:

```
client = HipChat::Client.new('HIPCHAT_TOKEN', :api_version => 'v2', :server_url => 'my.company.com')
```

Then try adding `https://` to the beginning of your company's name.

```
client = HipChat::Client.new('HIPCHAT_TOKEN', :api_version => 'v2', :server_url => 'https://my.company.com')
```